# How to use update property of Grails submitToRemote

Tags: ajax, grails, gsp

I wanna use the `<g:submitToRemote value="Submit" update="[success:'resultContent',failure:'errorPage']" action="submit" />`
to enable update the `resultContent` div when the validation is passed, but update the `errorPage` div when the validation is not passed.

But I don't know how to let the grails know that the validation is not passed. This is the code I use

In the controller

```
def error=validate(params)
def user=User.get(1)
try{
    if(error){
        params.error=error

        throw new Exception("Validation Failure")

    }else{
        render(view:'result')
    }
}
catch(Exception e){
    render(view:'error')
}
```

In the gsp

```
...
<div id="errorPage"></div>
...
<div id="resultContent"></div>
...
```

What I want is to update the `resultContent` when all the values are valid, but to update the `errorPage` when there is some validation errors. The `resultContent` div is updated. But the `errorPage` is untouched.
How can I let the grails know the `errorPage` div should be updated??
I guess I should make some changes in the controller to let the gsp page know that the validation is in a "failure" state. But I can't find an example online to do this. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to create a new `User` based on params you can do something like this:

```
def user = new User(params)
user.validate()

if ( user.hasErrors() ) {
    render template: 'error', model: [user: user], status: '403'
} else {
    render view: 'result'
}
```